# How this process running in the background?

Tags: rhel, process, javascript

```
user   1550      1  0 Jun19 ?        00:00:00 node /usr/bin/nodemon src/server.js
user  11051   1550  0 Jun19 ?        00:00:38 /usr/bin/node src/server.js
```

Can someone tell how this process running in the background? The user is not logged in.

Answer (score 1):

It's probably `nohup`ped. The third column is the parent PID and for the first row it shows 1, which is the `init` process. This is what happens when `nohup` is used. A process may be started from another process with, say, PID of `1234`. This number becomes the new process's parent PID. But once the user ends, the session and so the parent process ends, `init` adopts the orphan, and so 1 becomes the parent PID.

Comment: To stop a nohup, u kill -9 right?

Comment: @SzabolcsMészáros What do you mean by stopping a nohup? Preventing a process from staying alive after the nohup command was used? If so, it deserves a separate question. `kill` is simply for killing processes.

Comment: Bit absent minded today, how to stop a nohup properly?

Comment: @SzabolcsMészáros Just put `nohup` before a command. See `man nohup`.